# Embedding assets, bitmap caching and bitmap transforms in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile

I'm sure these topics have been beaten to death already, but I have a very specific question that I have been unable to find answers for.

What I'm doing in my program is embedding several art assets for use, scaling them to support multiple mobile platforms and then going on my way.

I've read that bitmap caching is a good approach to improving performance of a mobile application. With respect to embedded assets, is this simply the act of making a single instance of the embedded asset and using it multiple times? For example:
`[Embed(source = "png.png")] private static var img:Class;
private static var data:BitmapData = new img().bitmapData;`

private var bmp1:Bitmap = new Bitmap(data);
private var bmp2:Bitmap = new Bitmap(data);I assume in this case, that all assets created using the "new" keyword will reference the single instance of the image stored in memory, and create a unique copy of themselves somewhere else in memory?

Next, with respect to the `cacheAsBitmap` and `cacheAsBitmapMatrix` parameters in the `Bitmap` class, will setting these properties do anything when using embedded assets?

Finally, when scaling bitmaps in AS3, is it more efficient to use the `scaleX` and `scaleY` properties of the `Bitmap` class, or is it better to redraw the `BitmapData` using a scale matrix?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there will only be one instance of the BitmapData you extract from embedded file. This saves memory, but does mean that changing that BitmapData will affect all Bitmaps which reference it - but if you don't want to edit the BitmapData itself, or you want it to update them all if you do, this isn't a problem.

Each Bitmap created with the `new` keyword will be a unique object in memory, but they will all reference the same BitmapData (`data`) for their content - think of BitmapData as the core description of pixel data, and Bitmap as a wrapper which allows that data to be drawn on stage. Each of the Bitmaps you create in your code reference the same BitmapData, if you want to give a Bitmap a unique copy of the data, instantiate it:

```
var uniqueBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(data.clone());
```

...if you want to access this later, you can do it through the Bitmap instance:

```
uniqueBitmap.bitmapData;
```

However, this creates another BitmapData object in memory, so only do this if you actually need to manipulate it individually.

As for the second part, personally I'd use the scaleX & scaleY of wrapper Bitmap if the scaling was for a purely visual effect (eg in-game) and frequent enough - using a Matrix won't resize your BitmapData, it'll create a scaled copy of it, so using this method for common transforms may not be ideal as you're creating a new BitmapData instance each time, especially if you're targeting mobile devices. It really depends on your purposes - can I ask what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for the info about the Bitmap stuff.. I'm going to run some tests tomorrow.

As far as scaling is concerned, the whole reason I'm scaling content is to accommodate for different mobile device resolution. Source textures will be 640x960 (iPhone4), but I want it to work on many devices, including ones of different resolutions, so I need to scale the graphics when they get loaded so that they fit into the device's window.

Reason I'm doing it this way is because using stage.ScaleMode didn't seem to work for me, but maybe that's because I was using Flixel.

Comment: Ah well - in this case you do want Matrix - scaleX/Y would need to be calculated each frame, so are useful if your bitmaps only need to be scaled for a few frames (ie an animation to shrink it), but will be calculated each frame needlessly (if you're only changing them once) - if you want a permanent transform, once-off, use Matrix. Hope this hasn't confused you, let me know if it has!

Comment: Yeah, I only need to scale it once and then use the scaled BitmapData at all times. I do not need to re-calculate scale every frame, because I want the images to ALWAYS be scaled.

Comment: If it's all good flag question as answered, otherwise any other help you need?

Comment: There is just one more thing - any insight about cacheAsBitmap and cacheAsBitmapMatrix with respect to embedded textures?

Comment: I don't know if you'd need to do this as they are already bitmaps - but for vector graphics they're certainly worth using, if there's ever a situation where you'd use it the loss of image clarity will be less noticeable due to smaller screen, and it will lessen the battering your application gives the battery!